# Find $f(x)$ by solving $f(\frac{x}{x^2+1})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I saw a practice problem in my pre-calculus textbook and I couldn't find a way to alias $a$ as $\dfrac{x}{x^2+1}$ to solve the problem.
This is the problem:
$$f\left(\frac{x}{x^2+1}\right)=\frac{x^2}{x^4+1}$$
$$f(x)=?$$

Comment: Try defining $t=\dfrac{x}{x^2+1} $ and then expressing the right hand side in terms of $t$. If you get stick, edit the answer and show us what you got.

Comment: I just saw your comment an saw the answer, thanks!

Comment: Nice, (and sorry for the typo: it's "stuck")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make it easy for you, here is the full solution.
As in the comments, let $$t=\frac{x}{x^2+1}$$ $$\implies t^2=\frac{x^2}{x^4+2x^2+1}$$ $$\implies \frac{1}{t^2}=\frac{x^4+2x^2+1}{x^2}$$ $$\implies \frac{1}{t^2}-2=\frac{x^4+1}{x^2}$$ $$\implies \frac{x^2}{x^4+1}=\frac{t^2}{1-2t^2}$$ $$\implies f(t)=\frac{t^2}{1-2t^2}$$
This implies $f(x)=\frac{x^2}{1-2x^2}$.

Comment: I knew I had to alias it to something then solve it according to that but I just couldn't figure out how, like it was some kind of mental block!, thanks for answering in such complete details!